# Packaging multiple Typescript projects depending on the same common local module

Tags: typescript, npm, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I'm working on a set of VSTS extensions. Each extension is its own little Node project with its own `package.json` and its own `node_modules` folder. The folder structure is as follows:

```
 - MyExtension
   - package.json // containing all dev-dependencies
   - tslint.json
   - Tasks
     - tsconfig.json
     - Common
       - common.ts    // containing functioanlity shared across tasks
       - package.json // containing all runtime dependencies for all projects
     - My1stTask
       - package.json // containing all prod-dependencies
       - task.ts      // containing task implementation
     - ...
     - ...
     - My6thTask
       - package.json // containing all prod-dependencies
       - task.ts      // containing task implementation
```

The way VSTS build tasks work, is that they should be fully self-contained. I've fixed this so far by copying the contents of the `Common` project into each task and then run `tsc` to convert them all to JavaScript.

This isn't bad but requires constant copying of the contents of Common to get anything tested.

I tried using local file references, added a dependency in each task's package.json to `file:../common`, which works at development time, but this doesn't result in the common module being part of the task after generating the extension.

My background isn't in Node develpment, but in C#. I've searched all over and haven't found a solution that works well with vsts-extensions.

- `npm pack` doesn't seem to work, as the extension expects all files to be there.
- `package.json/bundleDependencies` looks promising but doesn't bundle the local file reference.
- `///<reference path="../common/common.ts"/>` works lovely for editing but still can't run after building the extension.
- project reference with prepend doesn't work, build tasks require the commonjs module resolver. System and AMD aren't able to load the modules. Prepend only works with the latter.

Is there a way I can make this work "seamlessly" without having to take on bower or grunt and simply get each MyXthTask to have a copy of the local common module in their `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried @matt-mccutchen's approach, but unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work with the VSTS build tasks due to the fact that these tasks require `commonjs`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es6",
```

But I did find a solution that works for me.

In the `Tasks` folder I've added a `tsconfig.json` which defines my default settings and includes the files from the Common library:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./Common/uuidv5.d.ts",
    "./Common/Common.ts"
  ]
}
```

Then in each task I created a `tsconfig.json` which sets the output folder to the current folder for that project and which inherits from the `tsconfig.json` in the `Tasks` folder:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./", 
      "sourceRoot": "./"
  },
  "files": [
      "InstallExtension.ts"
  ]
}
```

This results in:

```
 - MyExtension
   - package.json // containing all dev-dependencies
   - tslint.json
   - Tasks
     - tsconfig.json   // Including Common by default
     - Common
       - common.ts     // containing functionality shared across tasks
       - package.json  // containing all runtime dependencies for Common
       - tsconfig.json // containing build configuration for just the common files, inherits from ..\Task\tsconfig.json
     - My1stTask
       - package.json  // containing all prod-dependencies for the task
       - task.ts       // containing task implementation
       - tsconfig.json // containing build configuration for the task, inherits from ..\Task\tsconfig.json
     - ...
     - ...
     - My6thTask
       - package.json // containing all prod-dependencies
       - task.ts      // containing task implementation
       - tsconfig.json // containing build configuration for the task, inherits from ..\Task\tsconfig.json
```

When compiling a task the following

```
     - My6thTask
       - Common
         - Common.js   // Compiled common
       - My6thTask
         - task.js     // Compiled task
       - package.json  // containing all prod-dependencies
       - task.ts       // containing task implementation
       - task.json     // defining the task UI
       - tsconfig.json // containing build configuration for the task
```

The only thing I had to add to `task.ts` is the following:

```
///<reference path="../Common/Common.ts"/>
import * as common from "../Common/Common";
```

And to change the execution handler in the task.json to point to the new location:

```
  "execution": {
    "Node": {
      "target": "InstallExtension/InstallExtension.js", // was: InstallExtension.js
      "argumentFormat": ""
    }
  }
```

And all seems fine :D. Combined with using `glob-exec` I've been able to reduce the build time to less than a minute when building clean:

```
"initdev:npm": "npm install & glob-exec --parallel --foreach \"Tasks/*/tsconfig.json\" -- \"cd {{file.dir}} && npm install\"",
"compile:tasks": "glob-exec \"Tasks/*/tsconfig.json\" -- \"tsc -b {{files.join(' ')}}\"",
"lint:tasks": "glob-exec --parallel --foreach \"Tasks/*/tsconfig.json\" -- \"tslint -p {{file}}\"",
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) with the [`prepend` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#prepend-with-outfile) if you are satisfied to generate a single file as output for each task (and use a compatible module loader) instead of generating individual modules.

If you need multi-file output, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939395) for a TypeScript suggestion and a potential workaround.

Comment: That looks like an option... It would require me to have a tsconfig in each task folder, wouldn't it? I suspect I could fix that by using `extends` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html I'll have to give this a try.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I can't combine `outFile + Composite` with `"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs" }`

Comment: Let's try a different approach.  What tool do you use to pack up the extension?  When you depend on `../common` in `package.json`, you should get a symlink from `node_modules/common` to the `common` dir.  Given that the tool is packing up the rest of your `node_modules`, can you get it to follow that symlink?

Comment: I may have found a solution using the tsconfig.json and output path. In essence building the common module as many times as I have tasks and then outputting the results to each task folder.

Comment: Structure can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks/tree/features/cleanup/BuildTasks

Comment: Not a fan of symlinks. They cause unexpected behaviour for people and are an optional feature for Git. What do you think of my approach?

Comment: Your approach of using `tsconfig.json` inheritance to add the files to the compilation is clever, but ideally in a general solution, one wouldn't have to compile the same files many times.  I'd be curious if you have any specific complaints about symlinks beyond the poor support on Windows, since that otherwise seems like the best general solution to me.

Comment: Well, my personal development platform is Windows, the build servers I use are windows and I don't have control over the git symlink support on them. And so far my experience is, that the `fs` libraries in `node` tend to not understand many filesystem features on windows. And I'm sick of all the copy-around-scripts I had before.

Answer (score 0):

Project references does not work good in my case so I used webpack with ts-loader to build my projects.

Place all ts code under single root with single tsconfig so it will be like this.

```
ts
 -core
 -plugin1
 -plugin2
```

Since 3.10 webpack allows [multiple output configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations). So we could use single config file like this.

```
const path = require("path");

const commonTsRule = {
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: "ts-loader",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
};

const commonConfig = {
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
};

module.exports = [
  {
    ...commonConfig,
    entry: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "ts")}/plugin1/index.ts`,
    output: {
      filename: "bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/plugin1/js"),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          ...commonTsRule,
          // here you can customize rule if required
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    ...commonConfig,
    entry: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "ts")}/plugin2/index.ts`,
    output: {
      filename: "bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/plugin2/js"),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          ...commonTsRule
          // here you can customize rule if required
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

So as final result you will have each project built from its own entry point and to its own output destination.