# How to use Typescript's references and build mode to compile a mono repo to a serverless bundle?

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, serverless, lerna, monorepo

Typescript recently introduced a new feature to work with monorepos: references. By specifying references you can build all interdependent packages using `tsc -b` (see also this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/30/announcing-typescript-3-0/#project-references))

This seems ideal for use with a large mono repo where some packages are serverless services. These services typically depend on one or more packages of the monorepo. I've created an example here:

https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example

While building works well with `tsc -b`, the problem is that the serverless framework needs to upload a single artifact .zip (to AWS in my case). When building a serverless service, like [this example](https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example/tree/master/packages/serverless-random), only the compiled files of the nearest source files will be bundled.

How would one use typescript's references feature for use with serverless mono repos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works for you to generate a single output file and use a module loader, you can use [`outFile` and `prepend`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#prepend-with-outfile).

If you want multiple output files, maybe it's worth filing a suggestion to ask for an option to bundle dependencies in that case; you would be the second person who has asked about this on Stack Overflow today.  Edit: [Suggestion is here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26565).

Edit 2: After extensive discussion, the conclusion was to enable the `nohoist` option on the final Yarn workspace, which gives us symlinks from `node_modules` to the other workspaces.  After we call `tsc -b` in the final workspace, the Serverless packaging tool follows the symlinks and produces a zip file with the correct structure.  No bundling is needed at the TypeScript level.  Caveat: Yarn seems to install devDependencies of dependencies in the final workspace, which seems wrong to me and confuses Serverless into unnecessarily including those modules in the bundle.

Comment: I'm fine with usign `outFile`, but `lambda` requires the function code to have an entry point, i.e. a `module.exports = functionName`. The `outFile` option only allows for `amd` or `system` modules, and therefore doesn't seem compatible with lambda?

Comment: In other words, Lambda expects you to provide a CommonJS module?  You may be able to use TypeScript's `amd` output and then add in [`amdefine`](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#nodeModules) to make the result loadable as a CommonJS module.  But this is a hack.  I'll file a suggestion for a better way.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for filing a suggestion! Would love to participate in the discussion

Comment: I also looked at using `amdefine` but this seems non-trivial, I'd have to somehow inject it (including its source since lambda requires all dependencies to be packaged) to the top of the built file.

Comment: Re `amdefine`: can you do that with a referenced project with `allowJs` and the `prepend` option?

Comment: It says `Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'.` The declaration option seems quite important, so I guess not?

Comment: I got something sort of working at https://github.com/mattmccutchen/serverless-mono-example/tree/amdefine: I can `require('./packages/serverless-random/dist')` in the Node REPL and the function works.  However, I realized another problem: there's no mechanism to copy `node_modules` from `random` to `serverless-random`, so you'd have to add all the dependencies of `random` to `serverless-random`, which is ugly.  If you opt to instead use another tool to copy the `node_modules`, then the TypeScript suggestion is of questionable value, but then so is the existing `prepend` option.

Comment: New idea: given that you are using Yarn workspaces and Yarn makes a symlink from `node_modules/@org/random` to `packages/random`, etc., is there a way you could get your packaging process to pick up `packages/random` via that symlink, the same way you pick up the rest of the dependencies?  Then you don't need anything special from `tsc`.

Comment: I don't really have a "packaging process", I thought that this is where the Typescript build feature could help. I expected Typescript to follow dependencies (hence the need to define `references`), such that it could bundle all deps to a single folder or file. Since this is not possible, perhaps my only way out is to resort to the old fashioned way of using webpack. There is an example here: https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/tree/master/examples/typescript -- however there are several issues with this approach, hence me looking to use the new tsc -b feature.

Comment: [One example of such issue](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/435)  and [another](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/436)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178405/discussion-between-matt-mccutchen-and-tom).